# ¿Cómo enviar los datos de mi backend a mi frontend laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo mi backend separado de mi frontend; en mi backend tengo una tabla en la cual se visualiza la información, pero quisiera pasar esa información a mi frontend, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

**BackendController**

```
public function getInfo() {
        $datos = UserInformation::all();

        $data['data'] = [];

        foreach ($datos as $index => $dato) {
            $data['data'][] = array(
                $dato['description'],
                $dato['image_route'],
                $dato['residence'],
                $dato['city'],
                $dato['year'],
            );
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

Esta es la información que quiero mostrar en el frontend.
[image: imagen backend]

Aqui se imprimen los datos de mi base de datos en un Datatable donde solo yo veo esa información, pero quisiera que enviar esa información a mi frontend.

**FrontendController**

```
public function index() {
        return view('frontend.home', [
            'title' => 'Ingeniero de Software',
            'description' => 'David Paucar es un Ingeniero de Software con mas de 2 años de experiencia en el desarrollo de sitios y aplicaciones web donde se han implementado servicios web para la comunicación efectiva; Frontend y Backend con el respectivo manejo de bases de datos'
        ]);
    }
```

Este es el controlador donde retorna la vista de mi frontend.

Aqui es donde quiero mostrar la informacion de mi base de datos.

[image: imagen frontend]

Comment: Osea tengo una ruta donde solo yo puedo acceder y ahi osea en mi backend tengo una tabla con informacion la cual quiero mostrarla en el frontend, pero mi backend y mi frontend tienen controladores diferentes, asi mismo las rutas.

Comment: Ya edité mejor mi pregunta

Comment: haz un echo del json en tu backend y en tu frontend manda una peticion a tu endpoint que devuelva ese json, ahi luego lo manipulas para mostrarlo en el HTML

Comment: Y el enviarlo por array la información directamente de mi base de datos a la vista ¿Si es buena práctica o una solución decente?

Comment: No entiendo, quieres pasar la funcion `getInfo` al controlador `FrontendController` en la funcion `index`?

Comment: @JuanRivera getInfo es la información de la tabla que tengo en el backend, pero la información de esas tablas quiero pasarla al controlador de mi Frontend, pero mi front lo tengo en layout por lo que no se como pasar la información del backend de forma global a mi front, porque si solo lo paso a una vista, al ir a otra url, deja de funcionar la información.

Comment: @DavidPaucar entonces, tienes un archivo que se utiliza en multiples vistas(algo asi como un header, sidemenu, etc) y lo que quieres es pasar informacion de la BD a ese archivo no? Si es asi, hay una solucion, pero indica la version de laravel que usas

Comment: Exacto @JuanRivera eso mismo, estoy ocupando la versión 8 de Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para compartir los datos entre las vistas, se debe usar `View::share`, en su [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) se explica como usarlo, pero lo adaptare segun tu pregunta:

1. Vamos al `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` y en la funcion `boot()`(para pasar los datos primero) agregamos `View::share()`

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('key', 'value');
}
```

> No olvidemos importar el facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

2. Agregamos el valor que queremos pasarle, en este caso lo que hay en tu funcion `getInfo()`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function boot()
{
    $datos = UserInformation::all();

    $data['data'] = [];

    foreach ($datos as $index => $dato) {
        $data['data'][] = array(
            $dato['description'],
            $dato['image_route'],
            $dato['residence'],
            $dato['city'],
            $dato['year'],
        );
    }

    View::share('key', 'value');
}
```

3. Pasamos el valor al `View::share`, `key` seria el nombre de la variable a pasar y `value` seria el valor de la variable

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function boot()
{
    $datos = UserInformation::all();

    $data['data'] = [];

    foreach ($datos as $index => $dato) {
        $data['data'][] = array(
            $dato['description'],
            $dato['image_route'],
            $dato['residence'],
            $dato['city'],
            $dato['year'],
        );
    }

    View::share('data', json_encode($data));
}
```

> Finalmente importas tu modelo `UserInformation` y listo, `$data` seria la informacion que requieres

Comment: De maravillas compa, funcionó como quería, muchas gracias.